# LARAVEL - how to retrieve data from three tables connected through two pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Following are three tables:

1.**users** (id, name)

2.**screens** (id, name)

3.**columns** (id, name)

**screen** and **column** are connected by pivot:

**column_screen**(id,column_id,screen_id)

and **column_screen** and **user** are connected by pivot:

**column_screen_user**(id,column_screen_id,user_id)

now how to retrieve **user** i.e. 'abc' and its **screen** names and its **columns** names via eloquent relationship ?

like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user1",
    "screens": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "screen1",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "column1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "column2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: through laravel eloquent relationship https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Latheesan please elaborate, "HOW"

Comment: If you have defined the relations on your models (so user -> screen and screen -> column) you can just eager load them in your controller and form the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up relationships first:

User.php

```
public function screens() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Screen');
}


// you can also build shortcuts through your relationships
public function columns() {
    $columns = [];
    foreach ($this->screens as $screen) {
        $columns[] = $screen->columns();
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

Screen.php

```
public function columns() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Columns');
}
```

In your controller/wherever needed:

```
$user = User::find(42);

$screens = $user->screens();

foreach ($screens as $screen) {
    // you can access like: $screen->columns();
}

// or using the shortcut
$columns = $user->columns();
```